# How to test if no event was invoked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, xunit

I am new to UnitTests and therefore to Xunit. I have wrote some tests, but I am stuck with the testing of events.

Is it possible to test that no event was invoked with xunit?

---

I used [this example](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/test/test.xunit.assert/Asserts/EventAssertsTests.cs) for preparing my tests.

The first test works fine. For the second test, I expected something like 'Assert.RaisesNoEvent'; However, that method is not available.

Is there another way to test that no event was invoked?

---

#### Code Sample

`Class` where Event is Raised when `Property2` is `Set`

```
public class Class 
{
    private int _property2;

    public event EventHandler RelevantPropertyChanged;
    public void OnRelevantPropertyChanged(EventArgs args){
        RelevantPropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }

    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Property2 { 
        get { return _property2; }
        set { 
            OnRelevantPropertyChanged(new EventArgs()); 
           _property2 = value; 
        } 
    }
}
```

`TestClass` defines unit tests for `Class`

```
public class TestClass 
{

    [Fact]
    public void ChangeProperty2_RaisesEvent() 
    {
        var cl = new Class();
        var args = new EventArgs();

        var evt = Assert.RaisesAny<EventArgs>(
            h => cl.RelevantPropertyChanged += h,
            h => cl.RelevantPropertyChanged -= h,
            () => cl.Property2 = 5);

        Assert.NotNull(evt);
        Assert.Equal(cl, evt.Sender);
        Assert.Equal(args, evt.Arguments);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ChangeProperty1_RaisesNoEvent()
    {
        var cl = new Class();
        Action code = () => cl.Property1 = 5;

        Assert.RaisesNoEvent(code);          //this is what I want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine you want to test a function which updates a specific row in a database table, you could test if the other rows haven't changed, for instance to verify the WHERE clause has not been omitted and is correct. But would you also want to verify if all other records in all other tables are unaltered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that the event was not raised by checking that the **EventHandler** was not invoked:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ChangeProperty1_RaisesNoEvent()
{
    var instance = new Class();
    bool isInvoked = false;
    instance.RelevantPropertyChanged += (s, e) => isInvoked = true;

    Assert.False(isInvoked);
    instance.Property1 = 5;
    Assert.False(isInvoked);
}
```

*This technique works with any unit testing framework.*

Comment: shouldn't that be instance.Property2 = 5; ? and would it still work ?